# Receber mensagens do FCM em aplicativo Java

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou pesquisando sobre **Firebase Cloud Messaging** afim de utilizá-lo como mensageiro em uma plataforma onde existirão sistemas web (Java, Spring) em uma ponta e na outra App´s (ionic) - ambos se comunicarão com uma API RestFull (Spring Boot).

Contudo não encontrei conteúdo de demonstração para fazer o **sistema web (backend) se inscrever como cliente do mensageiro**. É possível utilizar o FCM nesse modelo? Se sim, peço que compartilhem algum conteúdo ou dica.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. Consigo vislumbrar a dinâmica do FCM, mas não estou vendo uma maneira do back-end se comportar como cliente (receber as mensagens). Que é a minha necessidade.